# The "fb-login-button" class

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

With the Facebook Login Button, the HTML5 version needs the code

`<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>`

but where is `fb-login-button` defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the first place to look is the [Facebook Connect JS API](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js).

```
<div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>
```

gets transformed into:

```
<div class="fb-login-button">
  <a class="fb_button fb_button_medium">
    <span class="fb_button_text">Login with Facebook</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

The "added" classes you can find defined in the Facebook JS. The `fb-login-button` class doesn't seem to have any styling applied directly to it, I think its just a placeholder (you can use `<fb:login-button>` in the same way.)